# String-Manipulation: Split this String delimited by a - character?

Tags: c#, string

I have following strings (I'm dealing here with the names of Tennisplayers):

```
string bothPlayers = "N. Djokovic - R. Nadal"; //works with my code
string bothPlayer2 = "R. Federer - G. Garcia-Lopez"; //works with my code 
string bothPlayer3 = "G. Garcia-Lopez - R. Federer"; //doesnt works
string bothPlayer4 = "E. Roger-Vasselin - G. Garcia-Lopez"; //doesnt works
```

My aim is to get these both players, separated in two new strings (for the first bothPlayers it would be):

```
string firstPlayer = "N. Djokovic";
string secondPlayer = "R. Nadal";
```

**What I tried**

I solved, to split the first string/bothPlayers with the following method (also explains why I put "works" as a comment behind).. The Second also works, but its just luck as I'm searchin for the first '-' and split then..
But I'm not able to make it work for all 4 cases.. Here's my Method:

```
string bothPlayers = "N. Djokovic - R. Nadal"; //works 
string bothPlayer2 = "R. Federer - G. Garcia-Lopez"; //works
string bothPlayer3 = "G. Garcia-Lopez - R. Federer"; //doesnt works
string bothPlayer4 = "E. Roger-Vasselin - G. Garcia-Lopez"; //doesnt works

string firstPlayerName = String.Empty;
string secondPlayerName = String.Empty;

int index = -1;
int countHyphen = bothPlayers.Count(f=> f == '-'); //Get Count of '-' in String

index = GetNthIndex(bothPlayers, '-', 1);
if (index > 0)
{
    firstPlayerName = bothPlayers.Substring(0, index).Trim();
    firstPlayerName = firstPlayerName.Trim();

    secondPlayerName = bothPlayers.Substring(index + 1, bothPlayers.Length - (index + 1));
    secondPlayerName = secondPlayerName.Trim();

    if (countHyphen == 2)
    {
        //Maybe here something?..
    }
}

//Getting the Index of a specified character (Here for us: '-') 
public int GetNthIndex(string s, char t, int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == t)
        {
            count++;
            if (count == n)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Maybe someone could help me.

Comment: Any reason you can't use `string.Split(new string[] {" - "})`?

Comment: No theres no reason.. Could use anything.. I'm just not that good in solving such String-Manipulation problems :))

Comment: @Oded, doesn't `string.Split` have an array of chars, instead of a string by which it splits?

Comment: @BartFriederichs - It has multiple overloads, but you are right, I was using the incorrect one (as for the chars overload - you can pass in a single char to as it is implemented as a `params char[]`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of your code can be replaced by using the built in [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) methods:

```
var split = "N. Djokovic - R. Nadal".Split(new string[] {" - "}, 
                                           StringSplitOptions.None);

string firstPlayer = split[0];
string secondPlayer = split[1];
```

Comment: that works in my case also.. But doesn't fits all Games :) .. How u deal with: "E. Roger-Vasselin - G. Garcia-Lopez" ?? There are 3 '-'

Comment: It does work because there is a difference between `'-'`and `' - '` in the split

Comment: Oh.. I actually didn't think about (spaces).. Ok Thanks :)

Comment: @eMi: Its the basic lesson in program debugging that you should have good observation and check closely why its not working...

Answer (score 0):

`"string".Split` can be used, but you'll have to supply an array of strings, the easiest way would be the following:

```
string[] names = bothPlayers.Split(new string[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.None);

string firstPlayer = names[0];
string secondPlayer = names[1];
```

Good luck :)