# Excel Macro that loops within cells and writes to new file

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro to get some data from an Excel spreadsheet prior to importing it into MySql linking table.

There  is a column of charity names and a column with a list of id's separated by commas (these represent charity types)
To for example

```
Column A
CharityName1   
CharityName2
CharityName3
CharityName4

Column B
100, 101,104
 (empty)
104
100,105
```

I would like this to write a new csv file as follows

```
1,100
1,101
1,104
3,104
4,100
4,105
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: you have basically the same problem as here: http://superuser.com/q/486294/160170 or here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13126533/1370465

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will quickly create a csv file  `c:\temp\dump.csv` with this format

*[Updated to handle your format
I note that you may have lost data as Excel has applied scientific notation to your fields. For now I have added an ugly workaround to pad out the 0's. Should B2 be a 30 digit field?]*

[image]

```
Sub GetEm()
Dim x()
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim lngCnt2 As Long
Dim lngE As Long
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objTF As Object
Dim vArr
Dim vArrElem

Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objTF = objFSO.createtextfile("c:\temp\dump.csv", 2)

x = Application.Transpose(Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)))
For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(x)
    lngE = InStr(x(lngCnt), "E")
    If lngE > 0 Then
        x(lngCnt) = CStr(Replace(Replace(x(lngCnt), ".", vbNullString), "E+", vbNullString) & Application.Rept("0", Right$(x(lngCnt), 2) - lngE + 1))
    End If
    If Len(x(lngCnt)) > 0 Then
        If Len(x(lngCnt)) Mod 3 = 0 Then
            For lngCnt2 = 1 To Len(x(lngCnt)) Step 3
                objTF.writeline lngCnt & ",'" & Mid$(x(lngCnt), lngCnt2, 3)
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next
objTF.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for that - when I run that I get:                           Run Time error '9' Subscript out of range  -                              when I 'debug' this line:                                          If Len(x(lngCnt)) > 0 Then                                                      -    is highlighted

Comment: @PhilBarnett can you post a sample of your file anywhere?

Comment: The macro ran ok (I had made a nube error), however it wasn't quite what i was after -  the first row of the outputted file was 1102307207308110 - what I was after was 1,102 | 
1,307 | 
1,207 |
1,308 |
1,112 | (where '|' is a new row) -   this a sample of the charities csv http://tinyurl.com/c92y9rh , this is the csv your  macro outputted  http://tinyurl.com/bmo66ua  , and this a example of what i was after http://tinyurl.com/cspaxmc

Comment: @PhilBarnett thx for the files. Your worked example in your question indicates the numbers are separated by `,`. - which my first code relied on. But I see these `,` are actually only formatting and your data is a long string of numbers that needs to be cut into 3 characters lengths. I will update

Comment: How would I filter the output to only write lines when the first character of the charity id  = '2' so just 1,207 in the above example

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through the second column and take the values from each cell into an array, lets call it mainArray. (This iterates rows and cols, be warned: [How to iterate through a variable-column-length range in Excel using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844044/how-to-iterate-through-a-variable-column-length-range-in-excel-using-vba))

Then I would parse until the delimiting ',' and store them in a an array called cellArray with the first value as the numbered cell they were taken from. Then, replace the original cell value in mainArray with the new cellArray. ( [String-Manipulation: Split this String delimited by a - character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955640/string-manipulation-split-this-string-delimited-by-a-character) )

So cell B1 would become  cellArray = { 1, 100, 101, 104 } which would be the first value in mainArray. Do this for each cell in column B for the used range.

Then I would create a new csv ( [How to create a separate CSV file from VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419828/how-to-create-a-separate-csv-file-from-vba) ) and then input the data into it.

To input the data I would loop through each of my saved arrays and store as CellValue = array[0] + ", " + array[i]

Lastly, I would save my new CSV file.

Comment: This is very high level guidance - closer to a comment than an answer

Comment: Thanks for that - I probably should have mentioned that my experience with Macros is very limited so I wouldn't really know to go about implementing this

Comment: No problemo. The links should explain the details of the coding if you're unsure. I've always preferred doing things the hard way, I guess, haha.